# Android scroll bug > only visible on touch

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

I'm creating a web app with PhoneGap 1.9 and on android I'm running into a problem, currently running on Android 3.2.

I have a simple ul list with li elements, for some reason the content doesn't get visible instantly when scrolling, but you have to touch the screen to get the contest visible.

I attached two images, that should be more explanatory.
To note, I load additional content when reaching the bottom of the scroll.

scrolling down with one move;

> [image1](http://puu.sh/Ng05.jpg):

touching the bottom of the screen - the content only now appears;

> [image2](http://puu.sh/Ng0F.jpg)

Other than that, sometimes the scroll also gets quite buggy, e.g. it jumps up/down when touching the content.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile? I know such problems in that.

Comment: I only use jquery 1.7.2 (not mobile as I just heard bad stuff about it).

Comment: Does this error only occur in the android application, so your web app (called by a mobile browser) is working fine?
Test your app on an other device.

Comment: Works fine on iOS, same bug on Galaxy S3 with Android 4.0.4.

Comment: In fact .. I just noticed it also happens on iOS on some places. Is anyone aware of any CSS property or similar that would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem before but I was using Mobile jQuery 1.1. Anyways it solved by using iScroll. Have a look at http://cubiq.org/iscroll

This might help you.